# What's an efficient way to concatenate all strings in an array, separating with a space?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

Let's say I have an array of strings:

```
string[] myStrings = new string[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
```

I want to concatenate them so the output is:

```
First Second Third
```

I know I can concatenate them like this, but there'll be no space in between:

```
string output = String.Concat(myStrings.ToArray());
```

I can obviously do this in a loop, but I was hoping for a better way.

**Is there a more succinct way to do what I want?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
String output = String.Join(" ", myStrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var s in myStrings)
  buf.Append(s).Append(" ");
var ss = buf.ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: I'd be curious to see the IL code of this and a String.Join().  I'd like to think they are the same.

Comment: I am pretty certain they do something similar.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't surprise me if they compiled to the same thing. For someone coming across the code later though,  String output = String.Join(" ", myStrings);  would be easier to understand at a glance.