# C# concatenation quicker

Tags: c#, string, performance, concatenation

I ran visual studio analysis on my code and i found that a large amount of time was spent concatenating strings. Is there a quicker way to concatenate?

```
    string[] infoseperated = info.Split(' ');   
    for (int iii = totalremove; iii < infoseperated.Length; iii++)
    {
    newinfo += infoseperated[iii] + " ";
    }
```

Comment: In that exact loop or in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's an efficient way to concatenate all strings in an array, separating with a space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850610/whats-an-efficient-way-to-concatenate-all-strings-in-an-array-separating-with)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `string.Join` instead:

```
newinfo = string.Join(" ", infoseperated.Skip(totalremove));
```

Your current approach generates a *new* string for every concatenation (since strings are immutable and you have to re-assign a new string), which is quite expensive.

For every concatenation all characters of the existing string have to be copied into the new string, so the cost of this operation grows with the number of characters in a string - it's a [**Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)

`string.Join` uses a `StringBuilder` internally which avoids this.

Comment: You need `infoseparated.Skip(totalremove)` to match the semantics of the OP.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Skip will have to type-check the array to see whether it implements `IList<string>`; the `Join` overload that takes a startindex and a length would probably be more efficient.

Comment: @phoog: Perhaps, if you need to squeeze every last ounce of performance out of this. The `Skip` version is frankly a little more readable, so that's a factor too.

Comment: is there a way to use the join so that it has a max limit too? instead of infoseperated.Length a varable total as the max

Comment: @Jason I just checked, and the array version of Join allocates one string by calculating the total length needed up front (which means it iterates the array twice), while the IEnumerable version uses a string builder (which means it potentially requires several allocations).  So the relative performance will most likely depend on the number of string elements and on their lengths.

Comment: @caseyr547: you can add `Take(count)` in the above example: `infoseperated.Skip(totalremove).Take(count)`

Comment: @caseyr547 the last parameter of Join is the number of elements you'd like to include.  So, if you want to exclude the first two and last three elements from a 15-element array, you'd say `string.Join(separator, array, 2, 10);`.  Or, with the other approach, `string.Join(separator, array.Skip(2).Take(10));`. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

you should take a look at the [StringBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx). It is meant for things like this.

Comment: StringBuilder is good for the general case, but for this specific case `String.Join` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you concatenate with the `+` operator, you're creating a new object.  Instead, use the `StringBuilder` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Text.StringBuilder. It has better performance than string concatenation.

Comment: And `String.Join` is even better because there's less code to write in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join`, `string.Append` and `string.Format("")` are probably more efficient than adding strings, however that doesn't mean that you will necessarily improve your speed as much as you really want to. You should try to look at the big picture and really determine why you're concatenating strings so much, if you can minimize that action then it might be better than just using the most efficient concatenation method.

Comment: This is wrong. `+` compiles to `Concat` anyway, and `Concat` suffers from the [Schlemiel the Painter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm) problem.

Comment: I have removed my downvote since you edited your answer in accordance with my previous comment.

Comment: @Jason, thanks... the point of my answer is that using the fastest concatenation method is good, but it's better to eliminate the bottleneck altogether (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StringBuilder`:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int totalremove = 0;
        string[] infoseperated = info.Split(' ');
        for (int iii = totalremove; iii < infoseperated.Length; iii++)
        {
            sb.Append(infoseperated[iii]);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        newinfo = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct to suggest `string.Join`, but they are suggesting the wrong overload:

```
newInfo = string.Join(" ", infoseparated, totalremove, infoseparated.Length - totalremove);
```

Comment: Or you can just use `infoseparated.Skip(totalremove)` as the second parameter to `String.Join`.

Comment: @Jason true, but the Skip call will have a little more overhead, so if performance is critical, the `Join(string, string[], int, int)` call may be better.

Answer (score 0):

As numerous other answers have said, using a StringBuilder either directly or indirectly through string.Join will be much better performance. However, in your example Split & Join, I think we can do even better.

```
// first, find the n-th (totalremove-th) separating space.
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < totalremove; i++)
{
    index = infoseperated.IndexOf(' ', index + 1);
    if(index == -1) return ""; // e.g., asked to remove 5 values, but only 3 in the string.
}

// return everything after that point.
return infoseperated.Substring(index + 1);
```

As long as infoseperated doesn't have any double-spaces, or a space at the beginning, or anything like that, this will be more efficient than splitting & reassembling the string.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is the greatest concern, the fastest method would probably be not to split the string at all and incur no memory allocation overhead except getting the substring;

```
string newinfo;
while (totalremove-- > 0 && (index = info.IndexOf(' ', index)) >= 0) index+=1;
if (index >= 0)
    newinfo = info.Substring(index);
else
    newinfo = "";
```